# Images gone narrow in Chrome

Tags: html, css

In the following link, in Chrome, for the life of me, i can't figure out why the images are being displayed narrowly and not their natural size. they each have height/width CSS inline, but in Chrome, it gets distorted. In Firefox its fine.

Would someone mind taking a look?

Thanks

link: `http://yachadzehut.org.il/about-us/?id=6`

Screenshot from Chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `max-width:100%` from img style

OR

remove `height` inline style for image elmenet